# How to include sid and port into an oracle connection string?

Tags: .net, oracle, connection-string

I would like to specify the port and sid in the connection string. After the following code runs

```
public static string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        string host = Config.CsHost;
        string sid = Config.CsSID;
        string port = Config.CsPort;
        string user = Config.CsUser;
        string pass = Config.CsPassword;
        return String.Format(@"Data Source = {0}:{1}\{2}; Persist Security Info = True; User Id = {3}; Password = {4}; Unicode = True", host, port, sid, user, pass);
    }
}
```

...

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
```

the Open() doesn't respond... The problem is with the sid I think. What might be the problem?

UPDATE:
I should use this kind of connection string. But I can't interpret it well.

Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Can someone help me interpret this?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to replace SERVICE_NAME to SID, so this:

```
return String.Format("SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})(PORT={1}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID={2})));uid={3};pwd={4};", host, port, sid, user, pass);
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid TNS format try this:

```
Data Source = server:port/SID; User ID = user; Password = mypwd
```

Comment: I think this works only if your SID matches Service name.

Answer (score 5):

Lets take what you have here

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID))); 
User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

This is `.net` connection string
This part here

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)))
```

is what oracle client needs to connect to SID. This part can be also configured in `TNS Names` file. In this case you will have something like

```
MyOraDbConnection = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=...
```

So your `.net` code will look like

```
string connStr = "Data Source=MyOraDbConnection;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

**2**

Now, it looks looks like you want to do stuff dynamically. Usually, people take bunch of text box values and concatenate them as this

```
string dataSource = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + txtDbServer.Text + ...
```

another way is

```
string dataSource = string.Format("(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})(PORT={1})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME={2})))",
    txtDbServer.Text,
    txtPort.Text,
    txtSid.Text);
```

Or, you can create ConnStr object which can do more than just concatenate strings. It may save your conn string - in pseudo-code

```
class ConnStr
{
    string Server {get;set;}
    string Port {get;set;}
    string Sid {get;set;}
    // more properties

    string GetConnectionString()
    {
        // return your compiled string
    }

    void Save(string switches)
    {
        // Save your string to different places. 
        // For example 
        //      /f myconnfile.txt - will save to application root directory
        //      /f c:\xxx\myconnfile.txt - will save to specific directory
        //      /s myconnsetting  - will save to settings
    }

    void Load(string switches)
    {
        // Load your string from sources. 
    }
}
```

This is more work but also more flexibility too

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string :

```
User Id=[user];Password=[pass];Server=[server];Direct=True;Sid=[sid];Port=[port];Persist Security Info=True
```

Comment: System.Data.Oracleclient throws an Exception, saying Direct and Sid are not keywords... thanks anyway.